# Android:Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one. works

Tags: android

Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one. works       Unknown Android Target Problem

This is the error i got on importing a package, wat could be the problem ???

Comment: Which Android SDK version do you use? Note that default.properties has been renamed project.properties since [r14](http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but

try to do as follow:

1. right click on the project
2. then, click on properties
3. then choose Android
4. then select the target

if you still have the same problem, try to recreate the project from an existant source

1. file/new android project
2. in the  window appearing, choose create  from an existence source
3. then go select your old project

it should work now

Comment: still the same error works] Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.

Comment: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read F:\androidwork\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-8\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\androidwork\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-8\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]      i got this after i removed all jar files and clean project then build, no errors but application got force closed had the above text in console .... ???

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing project create a new project using existing source:

File > New > Android Project > Check "Create project from existing source"

Comment: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read F:\androidwork\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\androidwork\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
[2012-03-16 17:54:58 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read F:\androidwork\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\androidwork\android-sdk-windows\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: When you choose "Create project from existiong source" you should select the directory of your android project which has a manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if you are missing the project.properties file.